# Server - Synchronous I/O Multiplexing (Sockets)

Tags: c, sockets, libevent

I have implemented a chat server in C/Linux that uses TCP sockets. It is currently using a single process and uses select() to keep the server from blocking. I've read that select() is a pretty slow method and I'm looking to upgrade the server to a more efficient version.

I'm currently looking at libevent but I was hoping that someone with experience in designing fast server code could give me some pointers on what some of the fastest technologies available are. Is libevent a solid choice or is there something better I should look into?

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: You should have a look at https://github.com/joyent/libuv .

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Do you have any reasons why you prefer this software?

Comment: It uses libev which is faster than libevent, it is cross platform, works with windows, and it has a bit of abstraction. I haven't done anything async work in C, so no experience.

Comment: You've _read_ that select() is slow - is your chat server slow?  Will using a faster technique really make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux (only) you can use epoll, which is faster in most cases (but not all).

The main disadvantage of epoll is that it is supported on the Linux OS only (not portable).

In a summary note, epoll can monitor a very large number of descriptors and will return a list of **only** those that changed (no need to pass over all the original list of descriptors).

Comment: I'm going to look into that. Do you mean epoll is faster than select() or faster than libraries such as libevent? Thanks!

Comment: epoll is a system call eventually, it operates directly on the kernel. Libraries may use epoll, poll, select or others to perform their work. They obviously have a small overhead, but it depends how you see an overhead exactly. On the positive side, a library is usually portable and may be used under several architectures/systems and even allow simple migration from one tool to another... it is an abstraction of the low level methods (like epoll).